# Obtener una sola fila del datagridview

Tags: c#

lo que yo hago es obtener una fila de otro datagridview1 solo mando a llamar la lista del otro datagridview2 y colocarlo en el datagridview1. 
Lo que yo quiero hacer es obtener solamente una fila de la lista no todos los datos. estoy trabajando con 3 capas.
esto seria mi codigo del formulario donde quiero mandar a llamar la fila datagridview2

O QUERIA SABER SI HAY OTRA FORMA DE MANDAR A LLAMAR LAS FILAS

```
private void FrmBuscarProducto_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        Nproducto gestionproductos = new Nproducto();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = gestionproductos.obtenerlistproducto();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR");
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {    

        idproducto = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["id_producto"].Value.ToString());
        costo = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["precio_ventas"].Value.ToString());
        tipo = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["tipo"].Value.ToString();
        nombre = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["nombre"].Value.ToString();
        cantidad = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["cantidad"].Value.ToString();
        descripcion = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["descripcion"].Value.ToString();
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Y ESTE SERIA EL CODIGO DE MI BOTON DONDE AGREGARE LA FILA

```
private void btnagregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    FrmBuscarProducto bp = new FrmBuscarProducto();
        if (bp.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
        Nproducto gestionproductos = new Nproducto();
        dgvventas.DataSource = gestionproductos.obtenerlistproducto();         
    }


}
```

Comment: Sugerencia: nunca hagas un `catch` de una excepción si lo único que vas a hacer es lanzarlo de nuevo sin hacer nada más. Es inútil hacer eso. Y si es necesario hacerlo, no uses `throw ex;`, porque esto causa que pierdas la parte importante de la pila de llamadas en los detalles de la excepción. Usa mas bien `throw;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas Gelder,

Para hacer lo que pides puedes usar `SelectedRows` de la `DataGridView`.

`SelectedRows` te obtiene la lista de las filas seleccionadas si tienes la propiedad Multiline activada, sinó te dará la fila seleccionada (obteniendola como `SelectedRows[0]`).

Te debería quedar algo así:

```
private void btnagregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    FrmBuscarProducto bp = new FrmBuscarProducto();
    if (bp.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Nproducto gestionproductos = new Nproducto();
        dgvventas.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0]);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Si tienes el `DataGridView` enlazado con un `DataTable`, debes añadir la `Row` en el `DataTable` y no en el `DataGridView`.

Comment: Hey marc! Trate de realizar ese proceso y me dice que no se pueden agregar filas mediante programacion a la coleccion de filas de datagridview  cuando el control esta enlazado a datos. ?m